# how to save the image locally from webpage

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How to download the image from the below link

```
https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?SceneView&ImageID=247572955&Version=-1
```

the code which I tried

```
import urllib.request
import sys
import shutil
imglink = "https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?ImageView&ImageID=247247011&Desc=Front%2FLeft+Oblique&Title=Vehicle+1+-+Frontleftoblique&Version=0&Extend=jpg"
savelink = "C:/Users/VM82958/Desktop/Nass_Extract/abcd.jpg"

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
   with urllib.urlopen(imglink) as response, open(savelink, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
else:
    with urllib.request.urlopen(imglink) as response, open(savelink, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)
```

Image is not getting downloaded only 1kb file is downloaded.

any help please

Comment: that does not look like a image URL... that should be something without that huge query string attached

Comment: That URL leads to an HTML page with a bit of JavaScript in it.

Comment: yes...I want to download the image in that html.

Answer (score 0):

The response you get from your `imglink` is not an image file but rather an HTML page that displays the image.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function init()
{
 document.getElementById("loading").src = "GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=247247011&CaseID=&Version=0";
 document.getElementById("loading").onload = ";"
}
</script>
<body>
<table width="100%">
<tr><td align="center" style="font-size:large">Images may not be to scale.</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">Vehicle 1 - Frontleftoblique</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">Front/Left Oblique</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><img onload="javascript:init();" id="loading" width="640px"  heigth="480px" src="img/loading.gif"/></td></tr>
<tr><td align="center">Image ID: 247247011</td></tr>
<tr><td align="center"><a href='javascript:close()'>Close</a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

the actual URL of the image is `https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=247247011&CaseID=&Version=0` to get the JavaScript to run and insert the actual location of the image into the `img` tag you'll most likely have to use something like [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) and then [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to parse the HTML.

Here's a script that will download the image (not using Selenium though) so you can see a way to do it.

```
import urllib
import sys

imglink = "https://www-nass.nhtsa.dot.gov/nass/cds/GetBinary.aspx?Image&ImageID=247247011&CaseID=&Version=0"
savelink = "C:/Users/John/Desktop/abcd.jpg"

with open(savelink, 'wb') as out_file:
    response = urllib.urlopen(imglink)
    out_file.write(response.read())
```

Comment: if any sample code to use selenium to download imag